# Data Binding Android 3 переменные

Tags: android, android-data-binding

Есть 3 логических переменных:

```
<data>
     <variable name="isSticker" type="boolean" />
     <variable name="first" type="boolean"/>
     <variable name="second" type="boolean"/>  
</data>
```

И есть `View`

```
<View>
app:backgroundRes="@{first|| second?  R.drawable.ic_bubble_mine : R.drawable.ic_bubble_mine2}"
</View>
```

Как добавить в `app:backgroundRes` условие, что если `isSticker == true`, то `background` отсутствует, а если `false`, то уже выполняется текущее выражение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
app:backgroundRes="@{isSticker ? @android:color/transparent :(first|| second?  R.drawable.ic_bubble_friend : R.drawable.ic_bubble_friend2)}
```